# Why FileOutputStream adds null and end-of-transmission character at start of the file?

Tags: java, file-io

Why following code

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream( new FileOutputStream("plik.txt")); 
         String test = new String("test");
         out.writeUTF(test);
         out.close(); 
    }

}
```

produces file with "null" and eot characters at start of the file, followed by "test"? I expected that it would produce file with only "test", without additional stuff.

Comment: It doesn't. DataOutputStream.writeUTF() does. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Javadoc of DataOutputStream.writeUTF():

> First, two bytes are written to the output stream as if by the
>   writeShort method giving the number of bytes to follow. This value is
>   the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the
>   string. Following the length, each character of the string is output,
>   in sequence, using the modified UTF-8 encoding for the character.
>   [...]

So it's not 2 characters but just 2 bytes.

The purpose of DataOutputStream is:

> A data output stream lets an application write primitive Java data
>   types to an output stream in a portable way. An application can then use a data input stream to read the data back in.

Also note, that's it's recommended to use the NIO2 API and the Automatic Resource Management. And don't wrap a String with a String. Also use a buffer for your streams when writing to the file system.

```
try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("plik.txt")))){ 
         String test = "test";
         out.writeUTF(test);
}
```

If you just want to write some text to a file in UTF-8, use the following code:

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("plik.txt"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))){ 
         String test = "test";
         pw.print(test);
}
```

Comment: "Automactic" should be "Automatic" (I am not allowed to edit this post as this would change less than 6 characters)

Comment: second version is not working - "The method writeUTF(String) is undefined for the type BufferedWriter"

Comment: @Bulwersator yes, I saved to quickly. You can e.g. use a PrintWriter.